# Sculpting window is not displaying "zbrush style" shader?

Tags: 3d-view, sculpt

I am not seeing the brown (clay) shader in sculpt mode (blender 2.81). What am I missing?

Comment: Share a screenshot/add a.blend file if you can.

Answer (score 1):

you have to switch to matcap :

[image]

After you have to:

[image]